# Split and Join string

Tags: vba, join, split

I'm newbie

I am need to Split and then join the string eg: a,b,c,d,e,f,g  to c/d/e/f/g

I am running the code like:

```
Sub test()
Dim MyArr() As String
Dim ArrItem As String
Dim z As String
Dim x As String
x = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
MyArr = Split(x, ",")
For i = 2 To UBound(MyArr)
    ArrItem = MyArr(i)
Next i
z = Join(ArrItem, "/")
MsgBox z
End Sub
```

but no luck, any help?
Thanks

Comment: does it have to be vba?  A formula will do it.

Comment: or just use: `z = Replace(Mid(x, InStr(InStr(x, ",") + 1, x, ",") + 1), ",", "/")`

Answer (score 0):

You have also truncation, not only split and join.

Single split and join could be performed this way:

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyArr() As String
    Dim z As String
    Dim x As String
    x = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
    MyArr = Split(x, ",")
    z = Join(ArrItem, "/")
    MsgBox z
End Sub
```

But first you have to discard first two entries, so you need:

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyArr() As String
    Dim z As String
    Dim x As String
    Dim x2 As String
    x = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
    MyArr = Split(x, ",", 3) 'MyArr will have "a", "b" and "c,d,e,f,g"
    x2 = MyArr(2)
    MyArr = Split(x, ",") 'MyArr will have "c", "d", ...
    z = Join(ArrItem, "/")
    MsgBox z
End Sub
```

You could also make all this in a single line:

```
MsgBox(Join(Split(Split("a,b,c,d,e,f,g", ",", 3)(2), ","), "/"))
```

Comment: really no need for the second split just use Replace: `z = Replace(Split(x,",",3)(2),",","/")`

Comment: awesomeeeee, thank you very much. i edited your code and it work fine for me     `Sub test()
    Dim MyArr() As String
    Dim z As String
    Dim x As String
    Dim x2 As String
    x = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
    MyArr = Split(x, ",", 3) 'MyArr will have "a", "b" and "c,d,e,f,g"
    x2 = MyArr(2)
    MyArr = Split(x2, ",") 'MyArr will have "c", "d", ...
    z = Join(MyArr, "/")
    MsgBox z
End Sub   `